# Adding an additional hdd to my PC in addition to SSD and external hdd

Tags: dual-boot

I've installed Win 7 on internal 128-gb SSD; Next I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 on 1 TB external HDD with dual boot. Now I want to add one 1 TB internal HDD and install Ubuntu 14.04 on it with dual boot. I've no need for Ubuntu 12.04. How to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Just install Ubuntu 14.04 directly to your new internal HDD, from a usb flash drive or optical media. If your external drive will not be mounted on any usb port while you are doing the installation of 14.04, your new grub boot menu will only include the list of options 1.Ubuntu 14.04 and 2.Win7 on SSD. Later you may want to format your obsolete external HDD.

This methodology worked for me many times, since grub only checks the boot options of available operating systems and list those when you do an installation.

Comment: Thanx for your kind advice.